# Creating variograms in a loop in R

Tags: r, iteration, variogram

I have a data frame of parameters to create variograms of different columns of a geographic dataset. I haven't found a solution yet to make the object argument of the `variogram()` function dynamic.

Here's a simplified example:

```
library(sp)
library(gstat)

demo(meuse, ask = FALSE, echo = FALSE) # load meuse data set

column <- c('lead','zinc')
test <- c('test','test')
params <- data.frame(column, test)

for(i in 1:nrow(params)) {
  # how to make the object in variogram() dynamic?
  v = variogram(log(lead)~1, meuse)
  print(plot(v))
}
```

How do I have to replace `log(lead)~1` to use the `lead` value in the first iteration step and the `zinc` value in the second iteration step?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create formulae from character text using `as.formula`:

e.g.

```
> v = variogram(as.formula("log(lead)~1"),meuse)
> v = variogram(as.formula("log(zinc)~1"),meuse)
```

and you can create character strings from variable values using `paste0`.

So in your loop use something like:

```
v = variogram(as.formula(paste0("log(",params$column[i],")~1")), meuse)
```